# Linux forward all outbound ip traffic to another IP

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, ufw

I am trying to forward all outbound traffic from one IP on ubuntu 18.04 server to another IP on another server but no luck.

Here is my shell command:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 46.XX.XX.X --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 142.93.XXX.XXX:80
```

When i telnet traffic still goes to first ip, anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Telnet uses port 23 and you are NATing port 80.

Comment: Is my command for forwarding correct?

Comment: I cannot comment on that, because there is important information missing What IP addresses does the server have? How exactly you are testing with telnet? Where is the traffic actually generated that needs to be forwarded?